# ReactJs display data in optgroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

```
this.props.datacat.map(singleData=>{
  return Object.keys(singleData).map((key,i) =>{
     if(key==='name'){
        return <OptGroup label  = {singleData[key]}>
     }else{
        return <Option key= {key} >{singleData[key]}</Option> 
     }
        return </OptGroup>
  })
})
```

**Data of (this.props.datacat)**

```
[
  {
    "4967": "Others.",
    "4968": "Sports & Beachwear > Others.",
    "4969": "Lingerie & Nightwear > Others.",
    "4971": "Pants & Shorts > Others.",
    "name": "Women Clothes"
  },
  {
    "4798": "Supplements > Others.",
    "4802": "Men's Grooming > Others.",
    "4952": "Others.",
    "4953": "Medical Supplies > Others.",
    "4954": "Personal Pleasure > Others.",
    "4955": "Personal Care > Others.",
    "4956": "Pedicure & Manicure > Others.",
    "6647": "Lips > Lip Tint"
    "name": "Health & Beauty"
  }
]
```

Above code which is tried to display the data if the key is **name** then to create the **optgroup** label else it will display all the data in option value. After that, the **option value id** which is **`<Option key= {key} >{singleData[key]}</Option>`** should inside the option value and the text to display is the value. Anyone know how to do this :( ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each entry of `this.props.datacat` create an `OptGroup`, then populate it with all the options of that entry except the one with the key `name`:

```
this.props.datacat.map((singleData) => (
  <OptGroup label={singleData["name"]}>
    {Object.keys(singleData)
      .filter(key => key !== "name")
      .map(key => (
        <Option key={key}>{singleData[key]}</Option>
      ))}
  </OptGroup>
));
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-vkj6k)